# how to make button go to the middle of another page

Tags: html, css

I will not add the code but I need to make my button not just go to another page, but go to the middle section of the page. Like I want the button to lead to a scrolled down page. Does anyone know what to do ?

Comment: Please add sample screen to get exact answer.

Comment: <a class="button-intro-below-left" href="">Click here for more</a>

Comment: it is just a standard button, I want it to lead to the bottom part of another page

Comment: .button-intro-below-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 49px;
  left: 1130px;
  top: 250px; 
  background-color: #53B9D8;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: spectral;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

Answer (score 0):

add id in the div of the page like `<div id="hello">some thing here</div>` and on button  you can use something like this `<button><a href="#hello">scroll</a></button>`

I'm assuming that just want your button to scroll down to section of the page. if i'm wrong then comment I'll edit the answer according to it.

```css
#hello{
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:500px;
}
.height{
height:500px;
}
html{
scroll-behavior:smooth;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button>
<a class="scroll" href="#hello">scroll</a>
</button>
<div class="height">
</div>
<div  id="hello">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way to achieve this would be to create a pair of  tags, one for the button and one that is invisible at the desired destination. A basic example would be as follows:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="#third"><button>Go To 3rd Section</button></a>
            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>My Second Heading</h1>
            <p>My second paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <a id="third"></a>
            <h1>My Third Heading</h1>
            <p>My third paragraph.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

After applying the appropriate css for your application, this would be a very simple way to link to a particular part of the page. The destination 'a' tag has a specified id

`<a id="destination"></a>`

while the corresponding button, which is wrapped inside an 'a' tag, has the href pointing to a particular id

`<a href="#destination"><button>Destination</button></a>`.

Hope this answers your question!